# How to add multiple Bitmaps in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, database, bitmap, slideshow, viewflipper

Please help, I have multiple image path that is retrieved in the database. This images are converted in `Bitmap`. I added this images in `ViewFlipper` to make it look like a slideshow but the next image does not appear. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
ViewFlipper flip;

DatabaseHandler db;
List<GettersSetters> dbList;

int index =0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flip);

    Intent goFlip = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = goFlip.getExtras();
    String getLocation = bundle.getString("path");

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    dbList = new ArrayList<GettersSetters>();
    dbList = db.searchFromDB(getLocation);

    flip = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    flip.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.right_enter);
    flip.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.left_out);

    String locate = "";

    if(dbList.size() > 0 ){

        for(GettersSetters currentClass : dbList){
            ImageView images = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            //This gets the image path in the database based on the index of recyclerview
            locate +=dbList.get(index++).getPath();

            //This converts the image path into Bitmap
            Bitmap img = decodeBitmapWithSize(locate,300,300,true);

            images.setImageBitmap(img);
            flip.addView(images);
            flip.setFlipInterval(3000);
            flip.startFlipping();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the images is from phone storage  ?

Comment: Yes the images are stored in the phone storage, but the images path are stored in the database which I converted in Bitmap for project purposes.

Comment: first check the Images are displaying correct before you convert it to Bitmap. check the path is correct or not

Comment: I tried loading first one image and it works, but I cannot try loading multiple images. And I tried loading all the image path stored in the database using TextView and it works

Comment: Is there any error showing in your logcat ?

Comment: There's no error showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, instead of what you have written in the *for loop*:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), img);
images.setBackground(drawable);
```

It is working for me.